# Common usages for chain of responsibility?

Tags: chain-of-responsibility

I saw a tutorial video explain the chain of responsibility design pattern, and I think I understand how it works but I'm not sure when I would really use it.  What are some common usages of the chain of responsibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GoF](http://www.gofpatterns.com/behavioral-design-patterns/behavioral-patterns/chain-of-responsibility.php):

> **Known Uses**
>
> Several class libraries use the Chain of Responsibility
> pattern to handle user events. They use different names for the
> Handler class, but the idea is the same: When the user clicks the
> mouse or presses a key, an event gets generated and passed along the
> chain. MacApp [App89] and ET++ [WGM88] call it "EventHandler,"
> Symantec's TCL library [Sym93b] calls it "Bureaucrat," and NeXT's
> AppKit [Add94] uses the name "Responder."
>
> The Unidraw framework for graphical editors defines Command objects
> that encapsulate requests to Component and ComponentView objects
> [VL90]. Commands are requests in the sense that a component or
> component view may interpret a command to perform an operation. This
> corresponds to the "requests as objects" approach described in
> Implementation. Components and component views may be structured
> hierarchically. A component or a component view may forward command
> interpretation to its parent, which may in turn forward it to its
> parent, and so on, thereby forming a chain of responsibility.
>
> ET++ uses Chain of Responsibility to handle graphical update. A
> graphical object calls the InvalidateRect operation whenever it must
> update a part of its appearance. A graphical object can't handle
> InvalidateRect by itself, because it doesn't know enough about its
> context. For example, a graphical object can be enclosed in objects
> like Scrollers or Zoomers that transform its coordinate system. That
> means the object might be scrolled or zoomed so that it's partially
> out of view. Therefore the default implementation of InvalidateRect
> forwards the request to the enclosing container object. The last
> object in the forwarding chain is a Window instance. By the time
> Window receives the request, the invalidation rectangle is guaranteed
> to be transformed properly. The Window handles InvalidateRect by
> notifying the window system interface and requesting an update.